# Should I use a "TList<String>" instead of "Array of String" always?

Tags: delphi

I have been migrating a project developed in Delphi 7 and looking at the code everytime the previous developers wanted to use a collection they created something like this:

```
ArrayOfString : array of string;
ArrayOfInteger: array of integer;
ArrayOfStringArrays : array of ArrayOfString;
```

This sort of code is repeated in many places, and also the "SetLength" for each of them several times, i wonder if changing all this `Array of Something` to a `TList<Something>` now that we are in Delphi XE4.

Is there any advantage in doing this, resource, speed or something like that to back me up in this decision?

PS: I come from JAVA and Delphi to me feels dark and full of terrors

Comment: Then welcome to darkness and terror! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Think of a dynamic array as being a lower level construct than `TStringList` or `TList<T>`.

The dynamic array offers direct access to elements via a pointer. The language hides the pointer from you, but that's essentially all a dynamic array is. But you are in charge of any reallocations and if you wish to insert or remove items, then you have to write the code, and deal with the details.

The higher level collection classes, `TStringList` and `TList<T>` are built on top of dynamic arrays. That is internally how the contents are stored. But the collection classes wrap that up for you. Higher level operations like inserting and deleting, and many more, are provided as methods. In essence, these collection classes provide a great deal more convenience than raw dynamic arrays.

To illustrate, consider the act of inserting an item. For a dynamic array you would do this:

1. Resize the array.
2. Move items that are after the insertion point from position i to i+1.
3. Assign the inserted item.

If you need to write this code more than once, well, you are doing it wrong.

For the high level collection you write:

```
List.Insert(Index, Value);
```

and let the class take care of the details.

Note that for historical reasons, and because strings are especially important, developers tend to use the bespoke, dedicated `TStringList` class rather than `TList<string>`. Again the dedicated class offers functionality above and beyond `TList<string>` because it specialises in strings and can offer functionality that is bespoke to strings. Again, the dedicated class offers convenience.

One place where dynamic arrays come in handy is when you don't want to incur the boilerplate of lifetime management. So for the desktop compilers that don't have ARC for classes, you need to explicitly destroy `TList<T>` instances. But dynamic arrays have lifetime managed by ARC. If you are synthesising arrays in one shot, and then not resizing them, then the lifetime management issue can make arrays more convenient to use.

As a rule of thumb, prefer the high level collection classes. They should be your default choice. Sometimes dynamic arrays are the right choice, but that tends to be for more specialised scenarios.

Comment: I rather not make a new question for this but, there is a project where everything is done with dynamic arrays, i wonder if is a good idea to replace those for TList<T> or leave it like that...can you advise me?

Comment: Impossible to tell from here

Answer (score 6):

First, in newer versions of Delphi, there's a `TArray<T>` type that can be used to replace all those old `array of whatever` declarations.  Using it can work around some long-standing gotchas in the language, left over from classic Pascal, and help you not run into confusing bugs down the road.

Having said that, TStringList is not a string array; it's a container object that holds a list of strings.  It has several specialized methods for string-list handling that make it extremely versatile: it can essentially be used as a list of strings, a set of strings (via the `.Sorted` property), a string/object map (via the `.Objects` property) and a string/string map (via the `.Names` and `.Values` properties.)

If you find you're calling `SetLength` on an array a lot, especially if it's anything like the following, you should definitely convert it to a list class:

```
for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
begin
   SetLength(myArray, length(myArray) + 1);
   myArray[high(myArray)] := values[i];
end;
```

With a generic `TList<T>` or a `TStringList`, this becomes:

```
for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
begin
   myList.Add(values[i]);
end;
```

This is both simpler to read and significantly more performant (especially with a large Count value) because the list classes are able to track their size internally and keep the memory reallocations down.  So list classes are a win-win situation most of the time.  There are some scenarios where you would prefer dynamic arrays, but they're kind of rare.

One thing to be aware of, though:  If you're from a Java background, keep in mind that dynamic arrays are compiler-managed types, but list classes are objects that need to be freed in code.

Comment: "...and significantly more performant" so it is true that lists are processed faster than arrays?

Comment: @sandiego206: I specifically meant *adding all those items to the list* will be significantly more performant than having to call `SetLength` over and over again.  For processing things, it really depends on what exactly you mean by "processing".

Comment: for the first example moving `SetLength(myArray, length(myArray) + Count);` outside the loop would be more performant, as the heap allocation will only be performed once. For `TStrings` and descendants, use `myList.Capacity := myList.Capacity + Count` to do the same (in later versions of Delphi SetCapacity calls SetLength on an internal array)

Comment: @sandiego Dynamic arrays will offer the best performance provided that you take care to minimize reallocations. However, I see no evidence that perf is your main issue. Is it?

Comment: @Mason In CS terms what delphi refers to as a list is really an array. Collection of homogenous typed items, indexed by a contiguous range of integers. In CS terms, list means linked list, of one form or another. The terminology chosen by Emba is unfortunate at best. A Delphi list has the performance characteristics of an array.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What is Counter Strike terms?

Comment: @PageNotFound Computer Science

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a specific need for and Array of String then I would strongly suggest a TStringList. I wouldn't use a TList at all, personally. The TStringList provides everything I have needed and only a few cases have I needed to resort to an array of string.

The TStringList can be accessed like an array via myStringList.Items[i] or even just myStringList[i].

You don't need to keep change the length or keep count, you just myStringList.Add(aString) and myStringList.Count (don't forget the -1 for looping).

Also it has the routines needed for all list manipulations for adding, removing, reordering, sorting, etc.

It can also be passed as a parameter without the need for other declarations like you need for array types.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And if you want a collection of things that are not strings?

Comment: IF you want to have a collection of objects, then TObjectList<T> is the tool for the job. It has all the pro's that a TStringList has but for objects. If you really, really have to use an array, then fine, but if you need a collection, then TObjectList<T> for objects and TStringList for strings.

Comment: You only use `TObjectList<T>` when you need the list to own the objects. Otherwise `TList<T>` is better. But what about a collection of integers, as per the question?

Comment: I didn't see the Integers array in the original question..oops. I have made a custom List class for Integers, arrays or a TList descendant could be used to provide the functionality. I using a TList descendant provides all the advantages of the TList that I mentioned above.

TObjectList.Create(False) ensures that the Object list doesn't own the objects for purposes of destruction. I don't see why TList is better. TObjectList & TObjectList<T> are derived from TList and TList<T>, but provide some more functionality.

Comment: Forget about the non-generic versions. Nobody is going to write new code using them. The extra functionality that `TObject<T>` provides is owning the object. If you don't want that, don't take it.